# Unable to Correctly Import Dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, jsoup, java-10

I am currently trying to make a web-scraping program with jsoup. However, everything I have imported does not seem to show up when I compile my program, and it errors out saying it can't find any objects that I reference from jsoup.

This is how I imported it:

`

```
import java.io.*;//for website
import java.net.URL;//retrieve url
import java.util.logging.Level;//log errors
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.*; //I/O stream
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;//web scraper
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.net.URL;`
```

And these are the types of errors I'm getting:

```
Images.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        for(Element el : img){// for each element, get source (src) url
```

Where Element from jsoup cannot be found.

This is my environment variable set up, since I thought that would have to do with it.
[image: env vars fixed]

This issue is very weird to me, because I seem to be importing everything correctly. I also have the jsoup.jar and the extracted jsoup files in the root directory of my project, if that is the correct way to do it. I am using the java10SDK to compile through cmd, and I have have tried using intelliJ ultimate to use their dependency injection, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have also tried to compile with java7, I am not sure if it actually compiled with it with the method I tried.

Classpath image as requested:
[image: fixed classpath]

Comment: do you really have JSOUP in your class path?

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson yes

Comment: @Sammy, then attach your  classpath configuraiton to your post.

Comment: Your setting up of JAVA_HOME looks incorrect to me. It should've pointed to the JDK10 bin folder instead.

Comment: @nullpointer i will try that now EDIT: No luck

Comment: @htpvl Like this?

Comment: your attached image is environment variables list, not classpath configuration. You can check whether jsoup lib is added on build path in Eclipse or Libraries under Project setting in InteliJ. No idea for other IDE.

Comment: @htpvl sorry, I will fix this now. EDIT: Fixed

Comment: Sammy, I have tried with my own IntelliJ, it works fine. Can it compile successfully on your IntelliJ or it caused when you comiple by cmd?

Comment: @htpvl does not compile on either for me. Very weird because I had a partner run it just fine on his computer.

Comment: If there is anything else anyone would like for clarification please let me know.

Comment: See [Add a library to module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#add-library-to-module-dependencies) about how to add dependencies to your modules.

Comment: @Andrey very informational thank you. however, issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul add **Maven** support to your project, because it is the easiest way to manage all the dependencies. To do that you just need to select your project folder in **IntelliJ** from the Project Toolbar and select "Add Framework support" and then scroll down until you see "Maven".

Once you add Maven support to your project you just need to Enable Auto-imports, IntelliJ itself will display you a menu to select if you want to Enable them or not, you have to select Yes.

Finally, you need to add this block to the new file created in your project folder called **pom.xml**, just before the project block closes (< /project>):

```
<dependencies>       
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
       <version>1.11.3</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Once you do that, now you can import and use the **JSOUP** packages in your project. If you want to add more libraries, you can check out: https://mvnrepository.com/ and select the desired version of the library you want to install and copy&paste the dependency block on your Maven file.

As a tip, I highly recommend you to use a dependency manager (like Maven f.e.) for your projects and always add it once you create the project.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking the time to write a detailed response. I followed what you said, and I believe I have set Maven up correctly. However, I am still getting the same errors like `package does not exist`. I believe that this may be a deeper issue that I cannot figure out. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Hi @Sammy! If you can start a new project I'll highly recommend yo to do so, I think that if you imported the dependency via JAR at first, now that's giving you an error. So if you can start a new project as example and try to add Maven dependency at first, than import JSOUP dependency as explained previously and try a simple JSOUP query. If that works for you, consider on moving you old project to a new one using Maven. If you need anything else feel free to ask! And if this was useful for you +1

Comment: @albarobartt Hello, I tried to make a new project and Import with maven again. It is really weird because my IDE errored out all jsoup things before I imported from maven. Then, when I imported from Maven they stopped erroring in the IDE but when I compile with javac it gives me library not found. Does this point to anything else I can try? Thanks again so much, I did +1

Comment: `Images.java:10: error: package org.jsoup does not exist
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;//web scraper` Theres 8 of these, either saying package does not exist or cannot find symbol when i try to use jsoup objects

looking into this further, I feel that it is a javac issue, as my IDE does not see any issues. However, I tried compiling with Java 7-10 so I am at a wall here.

Comment: @Sammy mmm yes, I guess it's a problem related to Java Compiler, sorry if I can't help you here! look for similar errors on stackoverflow maybe you found the solution for that!

Comment: i figured it out.. it was my ANTIVIRUS! Hilariously enough i have a new problem that you might actually be able to easily answer. Basically, my program works on macs but not windows for some file permission reasons. What would be the correct way to save an image as a file, since I am getting "FileNotFoundException" and it is pointing to my folderpath/"url of website.png" which is not working because it is searching for a file name (the URL) that is not there.

Comment: @Sammy yes, that's because the method to access directories in Mac and Windows using Java are different, check the docs!

Comment: @albarobartt exactly! except i created this on windows and cant figure it out!